# Where is the MVVM in knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Perhaps a dumb question, but the documentation of knockoutjs tells, that knockoutjs is a MVVM framework.

What i can see is that there is a viewmodel (a javascript object), a html Template, the view, with the binding to the viewmodel (uses of observables).

But why is it called a MVVM framework? I can only see the "MV" of the MVVM.

Comment: I don't think marking this question as duplicate of the question "What does Model View ViewModel / Knockout solve" is correct because this question clearly states that why is it called MVVM while from the OP's point of view it seems Model-View (MV). The other question is quite generic and for which some of the answers already suggest to ask specific question while this question is quite specific. Nevertheless Anders answer to this question is correct.

Answer (score 5):

MVVM stands for Model View ViewModel

A better name but not as fluent would be Model ViewModel View MVMV.

The Model is the data you get from server, it's often very much like the domain entity from database or other data source.

Its converted on the client to a ViewModel which is optimized to better databind against the View.

edit: For some Models like `{ name: "foo", id: 1 }` you never convert it to a ViewModel you just bind it directly. You can then say that the Model acts as both Model and ViewModel

Comment: Thank you! This sounds logic.